# Activate a panel in tabbed panels

Tags: pyqgis

I have to tab some panels:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

dws =  iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QDockWidget)
parent = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, 'Layers')
dockstate = iface.mainWindow().dockWidgetArea(parent)
for d in dws:
    if d is not parent:
        if iface.mainWindow().dockWidgetArea(d) == dockstate and d.isHidden()==False:
            print d.objectName()
            iface.mainWindow().tabifyDockWidget(parent,d)
```

How can I activate the parent?

Comment: What about switching `parent, d` around? I.e. `iface.mainWindow().tabifyDockWidget(d, parent)`. The [tabifyDockWidget method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html#tabifyDockWidget) is essentially just swapping the dock widgets :)

Comment: Good idea, but does not work, because if the first 2 panels are tabbed, they cant be tabbed again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parent.raise_() does the magic.
Here the working code:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

dws =  iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QDockWidget)
parent = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, 'Layers')
dockstate = iface.mainWindow().dockWidgetArea(parent)
for d in dws:
    if d is not parent:
        if iface.mainWindow().dockWidgetArea(d) == dockstate and d.isHidden()==False:
            iface.mainWindow().tabifyDockWidget(parent,d)
parent.raise_()
```