# How to retrieve text from a QLineEdit in a tabifyDockWidget

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, pyqt, qt-designer

I've write a plugin that calls a tool when a certain push button in my tabifyDockWidget is clicked. When the comboBox button is clicked it works perfectly carring the `comboBox.currentText()` to the tool, but when the lineEdit button is clicked the tool is called but doesnt get the `lineEdit.text()`.

```py
imports...
    def run(self):
        if not self.pluginIsActive:
            self.pluginIsActive = True
            if self.dockwidget == None:
                self.dockwidget = revEnvDockWidget()
            self.dockwidget.closingPlugin.connect(self.onClosePlugin)
            self.iface.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.dockwidget)
            self.dockwidget.show()

            #  sets the text that must be passed to tool
            #  QComboBox
            acquisitionTxt1 = self.dockwidget.acquisitionTab_comboBox.currentText()
            editionTxt1 = self.dockwidget.editionTab_comboBox.currentText()
            #  QLineEdit
            acquisitionTxt2 = self.dockwidget.acquisitionTab_lineEdit.text()
            editionTxt2 = self.dockwidget.editionTab_lineEdit.text()

            #  sets tool, it's the same tool for each different text
            a_ComboBoxClicked = HookCreator(self.iface.mapCanvas(), acquisitionTxt1)
            a_lineEditClicked = HookCreator(self.iface.mapCanvas(), acquisitionTxt2)
            e_ComboBoxClicked = HookCreator(self.iface.mapCanvas(), editionTxt1)
            e_lineEditClicked = HookCreator(self.iface.mapCanvas(), editionTxt2)

            #  calls the tool when certain button is clicked
            self.dockwidget.acquisitionTab_pushButton1.clicked.connect(
                lambda: self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(a_ComboBoxClicked))

            self.dockwidget.acquisitionTab_pushButton2.clicked.connect(
                lambda: self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(a_lineEditClicked))

            self.dockwidget.editionTab_pushButton1.clicked.connect(
                lambda: self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(e_ComboBoxClicked))

            self.dockwidget.editionTab_pushButton2.clicked.connect(
                lambda: self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(e_lineEditClicked))
```

[image: tabifyDockWidget]

```py
from qgis import core
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsFeature, QgsGeometry, QgsPointXY
from qgis.gui import QgsMapTool
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import Qt


class HookCreator(QgsMapTool):
    def __init__(self, canvas, txt):
        self.canvas = canvas
        QgsMapTool.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        self.txt = txt
        self.x = float
        self.y = float

    def canvasPressEvent(self, event):
        point = self.toMapCoordinates(self.canvas.mouseLastXY())
        self.x = point[0]
        self.y = point[1]

    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, event):
        features = []
        layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('aux_revisao_p')[0]
        pr = layer.dataProvider()
        feature = core.QgsFeature(layer.fields())
        geom = QgsGeometry().fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(self.x, self.y))
        feature.setGeometry(geom)
        features.append(feature)
        for feat in features:
            feat[1] = self.txt
            feat[3] = 2
            feat[4] = 999
            feat[5] = 999
            if event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
                self.canvas.unsetMapTool(self)
            else:
                pr.addFeature(feat)
                layer.commitChanges()
                layer.triggerRepaint()
```

I've been searching about and find this question [Activate a panel in tabbed panels](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257603/activate-a-panel-in-tabbed-panels) that mentioned a findChild/Children method but I couldn't apply it. Am I missing somethig?

Comment: Perhaps you could show the code in your `HookCreator` class since you are passing the line edit text to its constructor.

Comment: Ok, @BenW, I've updated the question with maptool code